Converting a Transform (position, rotation, and scale) from TouchDesigner Coordinate System to Unreal Engine's
I am trying to convert a transform from the Touch Designer Coordinate System to the Unreal Engine Coordinate System (and others).
Ideally, I want to take a position, rotation (in Euler angles), and a scale as input.
In the past I somehow came up with a method that seemed to be working for different coordinate systems (but isn't working in this case for some reason) so I must have misunderstood something. Math isn't my strong point, so if you can please explain the answer clearly, especially if there are some magic numbers. My ultimate goal is to have a complete explanation on how to solve this issue as well as create a generic formula for converting between any cartesian coordiante system given the up, right, and forward vectors.
In my previous attempt, I first figured out if a coordinate system was Left or Right handed, identified the directional vectors (forward, right, up) and then tried to equate them to each other. Below is an example using the coordinate systems for UE, Unity, and TouchDesigner (please excuse the omission of scale). As I mentioned before, this does not seem to be working as intended when converting transforms from TouchDesigner to Unreal Engine.
I should also mention that I am actually using my Unity -> UE form right now successfully in another program, it's actually the TouchDesigner -> UE function that is having trouble. I can only assume my attempted solution accidentally works only in the Unity/UE case.
** Please note that I am using Quaternions and not Euler angles**
** If using a different format such as a TRS matrix please feel free to use it as long as you can explain it. **
Source Coordinate Systems
---------------------------------
TD (Right handed)
X = right
Y = up
Z = backwards

Unreal (Left handed)
X = forwards
Y = right
Z = up

Unity (Left handed)
X = right
Y = up
Z = forwards

Position Conversions
-------------------------
UE <-> TD
TD_X = right     =  UE_Y
TD_Y = up        =  UE_Z
TD_Z = backwards = -UE_X

TD_X =  UE_Y
TD_Y =  UE_Z
TD_Z = -UE_X

UE_X = -TD_Z
UE_Y =  TD_X
UE_Z =  TD_Y

TD <-> Unity
U_X = right   =  TD_X
U_Y = up      =  TD_Y
U_Z = forward = -TD_Z

U_X =  TD_X
U_Y =  TD_Y
U_Z = -TD_Z

TD_X =  U_X
TD_Y =  U_Y
TD_Z = -U_Z

Unity -> UE
U_X = right   =  UE_Y
U_Y = up      =  UE_Z
U_Z = forward =  UE_X

U_X = UE_Y
U_Y = UE_Z
U_Z = UE_X

UE_X = U_Z
UE_Y = U_X
UE_Z = U_Y

Rotation Conversions
--------------------------
*** To switch hands multiply XYZ by -1 (leave W as is)
UE <-> TD
TD_X = right     =  UE_Y
TD_Y = up        =  UE_Z
TD_Z = backwards = -UE_X
TD_W = UE_W

// Convert coordinate space
TD_X = right     = -1 *  UE_Y
TD_Y = up        = -1 *  UE_Z
TD_Z = backwards = -1 * -UE_X
TD_W = UE_W

TD_X = -UE_Y
TD_Y = -UE_Z
TD_Z =  UE_X
TD_W =  UE_W

UE_X =  TD_Z
UE_Y = -TD_X
UE_Z = -TD_Y
UE_W =  TD_W

TD <-> Unity
U_X = right   =  TD_X
U_Y = up      =  TD_Y
U_Z = forward = -TD_Z
U_W = TD_W

//Convert coordinate space
U_X = -1 *  TD_X
U_Y = -1 *  TD_Y
U_Z = -1 * -TD_Z
U_W = TD_W

U_X = -TD_X
U_Y = -TD_Y
U_Z = TD_Z
U_W = TD_W

TD_X = -U_X
TD_Y = -U_Y
TD_Z = U_Z
TD_W = U_W

Unity -> UE
U_X = right   =  UE_Y
U_Y = up      =  UE_Z
U_Z = forward =  UE_X
U_W = UE_W

U_X = UE_Y
U_Y = UE_Z
U_Z = UE_X
U_W = UE_W

UE_X = U_Z
UE_Y = U_X
UE_Z = U_Y
UE_W = U_W


It's not clear to me what you want. Do you want the change-of-basis matrix between two (orthonormal) frames? Do you want to know how to convert quaternions from one frame to another? You already wrote down the conversion between the two systems, why is that not enough? Are you using Euler angles or quaternions (you seem to contradict yourself at the beginning and end of your post)?

Sorry about the confusion, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by change-of-basis matrix between two frames so please bear with me. My goal is to convert a position, rotation, and scale from the TouchDesigner coordiante system to the Unreal Engine coordinate system. Although the original rotations are in Euler angles I used quaternions for rotations because I thought that would be easier to work with. The method I included does not seem to be working as intended (objects in Unreal engine require an additional 90 degree rotation to match the original TouchDesigner render).

Let $U$ subscripts denote Unreal coordinates and $T$ denote Touch Designer coordinates.
You wrote out the relationships between the two frames. That takes care of position (assuming they have the same origin).
$$
  (x_U, y_U, z_U) = (-z_T, x_T, y_T).
$$
If $q = w + \mathbf v$ is a unit quaternion (representing a rotation) with real part $w$ and imaginary part $\mathbf v$, then $\mathbf v$ can be regarded as a vector parallel to the rotation axis. All we have to do, then, is transform $\mathbf v$ like it's a position vector while making sure $|\mathbf v|$ stays the same, and accounting for orientation. But your particular transformation is orthogonal, meaning it preserves lengths and angles, so you don't have to worry about $|\mathbf v|$ and just have to transform $\mathbf v$ the same way you do position; your transformation is orientation-reversing, so we throw in a minus sign.
$$
  (w_U,x_U,y_U,z_U) = (w_T, z_T, -x_T, -y_T).
$$
If by "scaling" you mean just a uniform scale factor, then this is independent of whatever frame you choose; no matter what frame you're in, all you have to do is multiply your components by the scale factor.
If this all lines up with what you've done, then perhaps there's a mistake somewhere else.
One potential issue is creating quaternions within the Unreal or Unity coordinate systems. These are left-handed systems. What this means is that a rotation around a (unit) axis $\mathbf v_U$ by angle $\theta$ that follows the right-hand rule is given by $$\cos(\theta/2) - \sin(\theta/2)\mathbf v_U.$$ Note the minus sign! In a right-handed coordinate system like Touch Designer with some $\mathbf v_T$ the same rotation is represented by $$\cos(\theta/2) + \sin(\theta/2)\mathbf v_T.$$

Suppose you're working in a frame $A$ and you have vectors $b^A_1, b^A_2, b^A_3$ expressed in $A$ which represent a frame $B$ you want to transform to. The matrix $M_{AB} = (b^A_1, b^A_2, b^A_3)$ (in other words, the matrix with those columns) transforms the $B$ frame into the $A$ frame; thus it's inverse goes the other way. We need this matrix to be orthogonal, otherwise quaternion multiplication (and maybe other things) will break; this amounts to checking that $b^A_1, b^A_2, b^A_3$ are orthonormal, and is equivalent to $M_{AB}^{-1}=M_{AB}^T$. The determinant $\det(M_{AB})=\pm1$ determines whether or not $A$ and $B$ have the same orientation.
A position vector $\mathbf r_A$ transforms as $M_{AB}^T\mathbf r_A$. A quaternion $w+\mathbf v_A$ transforms as $w + \det(M_{AB})M_{AB}^T\mathbf v_A$. Uniform scale factors do not transform.

I think I followed everything up to the creating a quaternion step. If I had to guess this sounds like where I am probably going wrong. I'll look into this a bit more and follow up with some questions if you don't mind me asking.

I'm pretty sure you are correct about the quaternion generation in TouchDesigner. The issue I have is how can I convert the TouchDesigner Euler angle (or quaternion) into the UE. It looks like the quaternion formula you provided roughly matches the 3-2-1 algorithm on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles). Would it be safe to say I could follow the code given on this page, but negate all of the sine values to generate a convertable quaternion? Or would it have to be specific sines only? or am I just totally wrong with this approach?

@BenjaminDangerJohnson I just realized I misinterpreted "forward" and "backwards", so I got the handedness wrong. What you have written in your post is correct: Touch Designer is right-handed, Unreal and Unity are left-handed. So my comments apply to those two, rather than Touch Designer.

So you don't need to negate any quaternions you create within the Touch Designer frame, but you do for Unreal and Unity. If the algorithm you linked matches the Touch Designer convention for Euler angles, then it's safe to use as-is in that context. Something else to look out for is that Unreal or Unity might use different conventions for Euler angles; the term "Euler angles" is often used ambiguously.

I appreciate your help so far but I've been trying to figure this out for a good 6 hours today with no luck. I've been trying to use the quaternions genrated by TouchDesigner, sending the values to Unreal Engine, reshuffling them, and finally using the Unreal Engine quaternion to euler angle function but the result always seems off. It's basically off by 1 or 2 90 degree rotations every time. Do you have any idea what that might be, or can you update your answer to provide a more clear solution? I don't mean to sound ungrateful but I'm having a lot of trouble getting this to work.

@BenjaminDangerJohnson I really can't do anything without more information. I don't know what conventions each is using, I don't know if you're using predefined functions, your own, or a mix of the two, etc. I don't know exactly what these errors are, i.e. input, expected output, actual output.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sure no problem.

I responed a bit more to your question in the chat but I must have missed you. Please feel free to respond when you have time, I'm off of work tomorrow but I'll try to check the message and provide any additional information you need. Thank you for your help so far.
